# Checking whether website uses JS function with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

My issue is similar to this [this](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2579), but instead of running the function and get the result by running this

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://vsemozhetbyt.github.io/test/test.html');

    console.log(await page.evaluate(() => test()));

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Currently this statement runs the test() function if it is in the website,

```
   console.log(await page.evaluate(() => test()));
```

How can I modify this statement to check whether the test() function is in the website basically I want to return a boolean value instead of directly running the function.

Comment: `console.log(await page.evaluate(() => typeof test === 'function'));` ?? This will return true if a function exists with the name test and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a simple `typeof` check on the function name to see if it exists.

`typeof existingfuntion` will return "function" whereas `typeof randomName` will return "undefined".

So, the following should print true/false depending on if there is a function named `test`.

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => typeof test === 'function'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, However this returns true if the function is defined in the JavaScript. I want to get if the tru objective website which I run this has the test function.

Comment: From your question `Currently this statement runs the test() function if it is in the website?`, I understand that the `test()` function is in the website you are running your puppeteer on. Right? If not then I will suggest you reword your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again, yes but I also want to use this statement to normal JS functions, for example when I run `console.log(await page.evaluate(() => typeof openDirectoryPicker === 'function')); ` I want to get return if the website has ability to show directory picker.